# Looking for thread IDs in AutoHotkey

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

I thought the following code may work but did not. The reason probably lies in the fact that the `Throw` command is executed in the hotkey thread, not in the auto-execution section thread.

```
try 
{
    count := 0
    loop {
        tooltip % ++count
        sleep 200
    }
} catch {
}
msgbox done
Exitapp

Esc::ExitAPp
^1::throw
```

So is there a way to know to which thread the flow of control belongs? Does AutoHotkey have a variable for thread IDs or something similar to it?

---

The below code shows that the both (pseudo) threads return the same number. So I need to know the thread IDs within AutoHotkey if there are. I've read somewhere that an AutoHotkey thread is merely a function call. But I'm expecting that there might be a way to identify the pseudo threads.

```
try 
{
    count := 0
    loop {
        tooltip % ++count "`nThread ID: " DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", A_ScriptHwnd, "Int", "0")
        sleep 200
    }
} catch {
}
msgbox done
Exitapp

Esc::ExitAPp
^1::
    MsgBox, % DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", A_ScriptHwnd, "Int", "0")
    throw
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
^w::
WinGet, WinID,, A
ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", WinID, "Int", "0")
MsgBox, %ThreadID%
Return
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As the AutoHotkey manual calls them threads, I need the AutoHotkey pseudo thread IDs in order to detect which thread the script's flow of execution is proceeding. I updated the question. Thank you.